# PHP downloading will randomly give a network error

Tags: php, download, ftp, header

I currently own and operate an online FTP, off a rented server, running on PHP and I am trying to incorporate downloads (as that is on of the most basic functions of an FTP). I have done this with the code below, however when I try to download my server backups which are usually about 800mb the downloads will only sometimes result in a network error. Which is very annoying and inconvenient. I appreciate any thoughts on why this would be happening. Thanks in advance! I only have 2gb of RAM.

```php
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("ftp://$u:$p@$h".$_GET['data']));
header("Connection: close");
readfile("ftp://$u:$p@$h".$_GET['data']);
```

[image: The downloads bar in chrome. Different downloads will fail in different places during the download.]

Comment: How long does it take before you get the "network error"?

Comment: If the error occurs, which is completely random, it usually happens just before the download is going to finish.

Comment: which server you are using NGINX or Apache2 or anything else ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set limits for PHP as well as for web server

**IN PHP**

```
// add these in starting of the files
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G'); //according to your requirements
//only for development will show some extra debug info.
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0=NOLIMIT
```

ALSO We have to set these settings (time and size) at web server level, I am assuming you are using NGINX

**IN WEBSERVER (vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)**

```
keepalive_timeout  60; #try this with 600, i thing your issue belongs here
send_timeout 60; #try this with 600, i thing your issue belongs here
client_body_timeout 120; #try this with 600, i thing your issue belongs here
client_max_body_size 5G; #default is 4.5 GB so you dont need this if data is less than 4.5GB
```

Don't forget to restart NGINX after web server changes.

for more info on nginx limits [click here](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/8658/nginx-cant-download-large-file-45gb)

Comment: My server uses Apache, so this is not applicable to me.

Comment: @GriffinGarman then you need to set response timeout & response size at apache2 level

Comment: RUN this command in cmd sudo tail -1000f /var/log/apache2/error.log and then try downloading your file if you got any error at apache level then it will appear in your CMD

Comment: Also make sure that `output_buffering=0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `header('Expires: 0');` and `set_time_limit(0);` before the `readfile()` and see if this helps.

As for compressing, I believe you would first need to download the file to the server before compressing it.

Not sure if there are free alternatives but Chilkat has both FTP and File Compression (Zip, GZip or TAR)

Example on Compressing: https://www.example-code.com/phpExt/tar_create_bz2.asp

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, could you elaborate on why adding ```header('Expires: 0');``` and ```set_time_limit(0);``` would help. Just so I can understand a little bit better.

Comment: I implemented your code, but it seemingly didn't change anything.

Comment: `header('Expires: 0');` just means the cache will always be stale (i.e. it will need to revalidate it first before returning it to a client) see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13158_01/alui/wci/docs103/devguide/tsk_pagelets_settingcaching_httpexpires.html  `set_time_limit(0)` Limits the maximum execution time, f set to zero, no time limit is imposed. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Do you see anything in Dev console (F12), or can you run a Wireshark/Network Capture on the webserver and trace FTP Connections. Would ideally like to know if the connection is being dropped by either the FTP Server, Web Server or Client

Comment: Nothing is documented in the network tab of chrome inspector tool. I download wireshark which seems like a useful utility. I then download 6 server backups 3 of which failed with a network error. Could you explain this to me:

> 38 0.000609 192.168.0.31 31.22.4.131 TCP 66 60228 → 443 [ACK] Seq=127 Ack=15929 Win=32632 Len=0 TSval=1412756963 TSecr=346646704

Comment: I think these are the ones that are failing: 1084763 1037.460648 2601:986:4100:ef0:654a:62e4:6f74:46f8 2607:f8b0:4004:808::200a TCP 74 [TCP Keep-Alive] 65189 → 443 [ACK] Seq=44980 Ack=52970 Win=131072 Len=0

| They are red in the Wireshark interface.

Comment: that's just a keep alive message so may not be related. try adding this as the filter `ip.addr == {{ftpServerIp}} || ip.addr == {{webServerIp}}`  

This may be able to help: https://static-course-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/IntroNet50ENU/files/7.2.4.3%20Lab%20-%20Using%20Wireshark%20to%20Examine%20FTP%20and%20TFTP%20Captures.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Since you were trying to download multiple files at once and you only have 2gb of RAM, it is likely that the rented server cuts off the connection.